# Ocaml module sig

Tags: ocaml

Could you explain me this code:

```
module type MP_ACTION_DISPATCHER = sig
    type t
    val dispatch : t -> MULTI.state -> MULTI.action -> MULTI.state Lwt.t
end
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the signature of a module (ie, the type of the module) which implement a type `t` and a function `dispatch`.

The function `dispatch` takes as input a value of type `t`, a value of type `MULTI.state` and a value of type `MULTI.action` and return a value of type `MULTI.state Lwt.t` (Lwt is a monadic thread library). `MULTI.state Lwt.t` is the type of thread that returns values of type `MULTI.state`.

Comment: I never found the implementation. only this definition

Comment: You may find out that other modules (in separate files) use the signature; for example it may be that this is used in a functor.